# How to fetch the username from other table using include in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch the username from user table of those ids which I get from response, my API response is :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "userId": 8,
            "leadId": 6,
            
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "userId": 9,
            "leadId": 6,
           
        }
    ]
}
```

I want username of userId in the same response.

here is my API code, this API is basically fetching the userIds which has the leadId 6 (user input) from Team table

```
router.get('/lead/:id', checkToken, authorize('admin'), async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const getAllUsers = await db.Team.findAll({
            where: {
                leadId: req.params.id
            }
        });
        res.status(200).json({
            data: getAllUsers

        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: "Internal Server Error",
            status: false,
        })
    }
})

export default router;
```

here is my model

```
const TeamSchema = (sequelize, Sequelize, User) => {
    const { DataTypes } = Sequelize
    const { INTEGER, STRING, DATEONLY, DATE } = DataTypes

    const Team = sequelize.define('Team', {
        id: {
            type: INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        userId: {
            type: INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,

        },
        leadId: {
            type: INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
        },

    });


    Team.belongsTo(User)  //creating a relation


    return { Team }

}

export default TeamSchema
```

i created a relation with User table too. Please help how to do this.

Desired Response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 16,
            "userId": 8,
            "leadId": 6,
            "username":"abc"

            
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "userId": 9,
            "leadId": 6,
            "username":"xyz"
           
        }
    ]
}
```

We can use sequelize `Include` keyword, but how can i do this in above API?

Comment: Does this help in your case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887542/get-the-data-from-related-tables-models-sequelize/33888746

Comment: yes, i got some help from there! thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the data from related tables (models) sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887542/get-the-data-from-related-tables-models-sequelize)